# searching for a particular entry in a table by qlineedit?

Tags: qt

What i want is that if i enter an ID in the textbox and then press enter,then if the ID is present ,then it gets displayed on the table the valuesof the table are inserted with the help of map in another window from which this window Box1 is opened as map.So as far as i have an idea,we have to run find command of map and then using if loop if that entered value in textbox is presentthen will display it in the same way as dummy data is displayed.
code used

```
Box1::Box1(QWidget *parent)
        :QDialog(parent)
    {
    searchgroup = new QGroupBox(tr("Data Search"));

    QHBoxLayout *layout2 = new QHBoxLayout;
    text = new QLineEdit(this);
    searchh = new QLabel(tr("&Enter ID:"));
    searchh->setBuddy(text);
    layout2->addWidget(searchh);
    layout2->addWidget(text);
    searchgroup->setLayout(layout2);
    tableegroup = new QGroupBox(tr("Searched Data"));
    QVBoxLayout *layout1 = new QVBoxLayout;
    tablee = new QTableView(this);
    mode1 = new QStandardItemModel(1,2,this);
    mode1->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("ID")));
    mode1->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("DATA")));
    map<int,QString>::iterator itt;
    itt=dataa.begin();
            for (int colu = 0; colu < 2; colu++)
            {
                    item1 = new QStandardItem();

                    if (colu == 0)
                    {
                            item1->setData(((*itt).first), Qt::DisplayRole);
                            mode1->setItem(0,0,item1);
                    } else
                    {
                            item1->setData(((*itt).second), Qt::DisplayRole);
                            mode1->setItem(0,1,item1);
                    }
            }

    tablee->setModel(mode1);
    layout1->addWidget(tablee);
    tableegroup->setLayout(layout1);

    QVBoxLayout *mainlayout1 = new QVBoxLayout;
    //mainlayout1->addWidget(menubarr);
    mainlayout1->addWidget(searchgroup);
    mainlayout1->addWidget(tableegroup);
    setLayout(mainlayout1);
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance
**EDIT**
what i want

```
void Box1::textReturn()
{
        bool ok;
        int id = text->text().toInt(&ok);
//      map<int,QString>::iterator itt;
        if (ok && dataa.contains(id))
        {

        //      add row (id, data[id] to table
        }
        else
        {
                QMessageBox msgbox = new QMessagebox();
                msgbox->setWindowTitle("Alert");
                msgbox->setText("No such ID present!");
                msgbox->show();
        }
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
void Box1::textReturn()
{
        int id = (text->text()).toInt();
        map<int,QString>::iterator itt;
        itt = dataa.find(id);
        if(itt != dataa.end())           //returns 1 if we found something
        {
                QList<QStandardItem *> items;
                items << new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(id));
                items << new QStandardItem((*itt).second);
                mode1->appendRow(items);
                tablee->update();
        }
        else
        {
                QMessageBox *msgbox = new QMessageBox();
                msgbox->setWindowTitle("Alert");
                msgbox->setText("INVALID  ID  ENTERED");
                msgbox->show();
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to display found item? Just activate this in table or somewhere else? And please correct your code.

Comment: like now i have inserted  a row with the first value of map.this map dataa is the map of whose first,ie,int value is what i want to search.if its found then that value and corresponding QString value is what i will display.and yes i will diplay in a table that will be containing only one row.for now the values that i have inserted with for loop is just the dummy value because of which i think you got confused.thanks.for concern :) @Blood

Comment: So the question is: how to add to `tablee` row from the map `dataa` that matches  number entered in the `text` line edit?

Comment: ya this is the thing i want.
i have filled elements of map like this :-
dataa.insert(pair<int,QString>(g+1,"HELLO"));
g++;
nd i have entries in the table of my parent window as :-
for(it=dataa.begin();it!=dataa.end();it++)
{
for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
{
item = new QStandardItem();
if (col == 0)
{
item->setData(((*it).first), Qt::DisplayRole);
mode->setItem(k,0,item);
}
else
item->setData(((*it).second), Qt::DisplayRole);
mode->setItem(k,1,item);
}
}
k++;
}

Comment: @KCiebiera Basically i know how to add using item and mode but have no idea how to take the input as an argument from user and then how to check if that argument matches or not.and also how to signal the event of pressing enter after user have entered the input

Comment: You can also add QIntValidator to text field. Then you will be sure can contain only numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KCiebiera said, you have to do this connection

```
connect(text, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(textReturnPressed());
```

Then you need to find your key in the table using

```
QList<QStandardItem *> QStandardItemModel::findItems ( const QString & text, 
                     Qt::MatchFlags flags = Qt::MatchExactly, int column = 0 )
```

As you have map, so elements shouldn't repeat, your QList should be NULL or contains just one element. When u'll get your element (as QStandardItem) you just need to invoke

```
tablee->showColumn ( int column )
tablee->showRow ( int row )
```

Where your column will be QStandarItem->column() and row QStandardItem->row();

EDIT

```
void Box1::textReturnPressed()
{
     int id = (test->text()).toInt();
     map<int, string>::iterator it;
     it = dataa.find(id);
     if(it != dataa.end())           //we found something
     {
         QList<QStandardItem *> items;
         items << new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(id));
         items << new QStandardItem((*it).second);
         mode1->appendRow(items);
     }
     else
         QMessageBox::information(this, "Info", "ID not found!", QMessageBox::ok);
}
```

Something like this;

Comment: but what i want i something like Kciebiera code as i have to add if else statement because if that value is found then it will be displayed and if not found then a message box will appar telling no value found.

Comment: Check out now. I think that should be it

Comment: Ohh you want to add to table key and value from key which user searched, right?

Comment: it says QTableView has no member append Row and theres some mistake in map defination .errors are coming due to it

Comment: Oh, my fault. It should be mode1. Now i have corrected. If no changes will be visible, add update() at the end of the slot

Comment: you havent used tablee anywhere so will it know that in which table we have to insert.like in my question i have set layout and included mode and all in table and so on

Comment: You don't have to use tablee anywhere because its QStandardItemModel define how your table will looks like. If u want to use tablee you can add after appendRow function, tablee->setModel(mode1); and then invoke update(). It will work. Checked that.

Comment: same happened here.everything worked fine but segmentation fault came when i clicked to open second window in which we type the id

Comment: thnx thnx thnx :D :D
it worked with both of your help.but last question that present id do gets displayed but from the second row not from the first row.one row is default empty.ehy so?

Comment: Change `mode1 = new QStandardItemModel(1,2,this);` to `mode1 = new QStandardItemModel(0,2,this);`

Comment: and last thing .how to hide the serial number of rows.at present along with ID and Data column its showing a default serial number column also

Comment: Probably you want to: `teblee->verticalHeader()->hide();` in the constructor

Comment: i tries it says it has no such member named vertical header

Comment: So please mark that answer is correct, that other users would know that problem is solved ;)

Comment: write now if we keep on searching in that box1 search option, then the entries keep on coming in that table but what i want is that after printing one value to the table,when the new entry is found the table gets renewed,ie only one found entry to be shown.
check edit2 in my code for the code which i right now have. @KCiebiera

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question. You need to create a new slot in the Box1 class. Let's call it textReturnPressed(). Then you have to connect it to `returnPressed()` signal from `text`

```
connect(text, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(textReturnPressed());
```

and here is textReturnPressed (I hope it compiles)

```
void textReturnPressed()
{
     bool ok;
     int id = text->text().toInt(&ok);
     if (ok && dataa.count(id) > 0) {
         QList<QStandardItem *> items;
         items << new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(id));
         items << new QStandardItem(dataa[id]);
         mode1.appendRow(items);
     }
}
```

You don't need an iterator to check if an item is in the map. Just call `map.count()` function.

Comment: thanks for help but what does this do dtaa.contains(id) ?
and what do you mean by add row (id, data[id] to table ?

Comment: dont we have to take an iterator for map and then run a loop kind thing and then have if statemnet in that?

Comment: bwhat is bool OK for?
if that value is found then it will be displayed and if not found then a message box will appar telling no value found.

Comment: First of all, you need to make sure, that there is a number entered in the text field. So variable ok means, we have int (not ab12). Second of all we have to check if entered number is in the map, it is done with contains. Than we need to add a row (number, map[numer]) to the table.

Comment: but it says QTableView has no member called appendRow :(

Comment: its also saying that map has no member called contains :(

Comment: Sure. Instead of tablee use mode1 and instead of contains use count funcion. I've corrected answer

Comment: you havent used tablee anywhere so will it know that in which table we have to insert.like in my question i have set layout and included mode and all in table and so on

Comment: shits.it compiled and all went nice.my parent window opened but when i clicked on search to open my new window then segmentation fault occured :( :(